# How to set parameters as optional while adding crystal reports in central management consol

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2008, oracle11g, crystal-reports

Recently started working on crystal reports. I need to do small modifications in the existing report(rpt) files.

I am using visual studio to do changes to report and then publishing to crystal reports server using publishing wizard.
But new reports that are published some how shows input parameter fields as values required. No option to make fields are optional to view report just like it was. Kindly note there was no code changes done.
Any one has idea how to make input parameters optional.
Environment: visual studio 2008, crystal reports server 2008

Comment: If the parameters are not required then you can try removing those from reportso that there is no parameter prompt

Comment: There totally 4 parameters. 3 mandatory and 1 optional parameter

Comment: There ìs one option when you open the parameter may be first or second in parameters... where you have option to set optional... currently dont have CR so unable to tell you exactly... try that

Comment: You mean open the parameters in visual studio or cr server?

Comment: Cr server you can set only default value to parameters, no option to mark as optional. In visual studio field expert shows parameters, but when I tried to edit I didn't see optional setting at all..

Comment: Yes open parameter in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

See the below screenshot which is in crystal reports standalone.. I hope this should be present in visual studio aswell. Option is `Show on viewer panel`

[image]